# How to use static_cast with a custom object?

Tags: c++, double, static-cast

I'm trying to use the `static_cast` that seems simple but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have the class Rat (used to represent rational numbers) and I want to cast it to a double. Then I could do `double x = Rat(2,3)` (it would store 2/3 into the x).

To do that I need to do a static_cast so I tried `double x = static_cast<double>(Rat(2,3))` but I get the error `Cannot convert Rat to double without a conversion operator`.

How can I fix my problem ?

Comment: What does `Rat(2,3)` return? And does your `Rat` class have an `operator double()`?

Comment: an object of type Rat with two properties : int numerator, int denominator

Comment: Well, the compiler cannot guess how to make a `double` out of that.

Comment: @J.erome You need to write the conversion operator.

Comment: @goodvibration okay I see I have to do `double operator=(Rat r);` and then code the conversion inside this function

Comment: No, you need to implement `Rat::operator double()`, or even `Rat::operator double() const`. Inside it, you should return the double result of your `Rat` class (without seeing your code, I would guess that to be `double(n) / d` or something like that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use `static_cast` if the type you cast and the one you cast to are related, or when the compiler knows how to perform that cast.

> Cannot convert Rat to double without a conversion operator

Tells you that there is no conversion operator for `Rat` that allows the compiler to cast it to `double`.

A conversion operator would look this way:

```
struct Rat {
 // …
 operator double() const { 
    // … perform a conversion to double …
 }
 // …
}
```

Depending on if you want to allow implicit conversion or not, you need to add `explicit` in front of `operator`.

Without `explicit` you can write:

```
double x = Rat(2,3);
```

With `explicit` you need a cast:

```
double x = static_cast<double>(Rat(2,3));
```

Normally `explicit` is preferred, to avoid accidental casts.

Comment: Out of curiosity why `const`?

Comment: @LarsNielsen a conversion operator should not do any changes to the original object.

Comment: Thank you for this really good and well explained answer. I got the "tadammm" in my head and I figured out what I was doing wrong. Thank you also for the informations of `explicit`